# Nesting hover doesn't work

Tags: html, css

**Before**

```
#item_1, #item_2, #item_3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 57px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#item_1:hover, #item_2:hover, #item_3:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

**After**

```
#item_1, #item_2, #item_3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 57px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover {
        color: #fff;
    } 
}
```

Leaving the html the same, the before version works and the after version doesn't. I'm building a Rails App with Rails 4.

Comment: I don't know. I've only created a Rails app and am playing with the CSS. If default is SASS then yes.

Comment: @user2469211 you don't even know the after version is SASS-stylish? looks like that's why it does not work.

Comment: @user2469211 SASS is not standard as CSS, it's some kind of extended CSS, so you may have to include some library/file to use it. I've not even used SASS before, just try searching on how to get started with SASS. That's all, I can just be sure your SASS version is OK, so the problem may be that SASS is not ready to run.

Comment: does the CSS file end in `.css.scss` or `.css.sass`? it needs to in order to be recognized as SASS. if it is `.scss` your code will work, if it is `.sass` you're formatting will need to change. i think by default it should be `.css.scss`

Comment: It ends in .css.scss but it still doesn't work.  @jakealbaugh

Comment: is there an `application.css.scss`?

Comment: Yes there is @jakealbaugh

Answer (score 0):

is a library of styles for ruby

please see documentation [sass install](http://sass-lang.com/install)

example

```
#main {
  color: black;
  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    &:hover { color: red; }
  }
}
is compiled to:

#main {
  color: black; }
  #main a {
    font-weight: bold; }
    #main a:hover {
      color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you either don't have SASS installed in your app, or the stylesheet you are using isn't in the right directory.

**check if it's installed**

check your Gemfile for something similar to

```
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```

add it and run `bundle install` form your project directory if it isn't in there.

**check if your stylesheet is in the right place**

navigate to

```
app > assets > stylesheets
```

and see if `application.css.scss` exists.

if it does, make sure theres a line that looks like:

```
*= require_tree .
```

if there is, make sure the stylesheet with your code is in that `stylesheets` folder and ends with `.css.scss`